# Web scraping in R loop for several elements. when receiving a whole number or inf it starts counting that element on subsequent loops?

Tags: r, loops

I haven't been able to find anything on this issue. As you think it would look on a csv. The counting starts when it gets to an Inf as below or 2020, and or 360, and other numbers in an element (i.e. cell). then starts to count, it has happened in more than one column in a file.

```
|:34145***  |:jocive: |Empyment:
|:34142***  |:NA       : |NA:
|:34141***  |:InF   : |Learnhnology:
|:34140***  |:1    : |Outlearning:
|:34138***  |:2    : |Christianity:
|:34133***  |:3    : |Histeums:
|:34131***  |:4    : |Relign:
```

I've tried to 'gc()' within the loop and I have tried 'rm(dataframe)' from the loop and many other possible remedies to try and start fresh each iteration and remove the counting.

Many thanks in advance if you have come across this issue and fixed it.

Thank you for the comments.

example of the code below: It is site specific.

```
rm(list=ls())

library(stringr)
library(plyr)
library(tidyr)
library(RSelenium)

remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
                                 port = 4445,
                                 browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()

#READ IN LINKS 
WebAddress <- read.csv(file with web addresses)

iterations = 100
k =10

masterWebAddress = data.frame (Name = rep(NA, k), Number = rep(NA, k))…                        
#CREATE SLAVE LOOP
for (i in 1:iterations){
  tryCatch({
    #Select WebAddress entry i in loop
    WebAddressSearch = as.character(WebAddress$WebAddress [i])
    remDr$navigate(WebAddressSearch)
    
    slaveWebAddress = data.frame    (a=rep(NA, 2), b=rep(NA, 2), c=rep(NA, 2), # up to bd
    
    #Variable a
    tryCatch({
      label = remDr$findElement( using = "css", "#block-system-main > div > div > div > div > section > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div.field-label")
      label = label$getElementText()
      label = str_replace_all(label, "[[:punct:]]","")
      label = gsub(" ", "",label)
      label
      
      number = remDr$findElement( using = "css", "#block-system-main  > div > div > div > div > section > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div.field-items")
      number = number$getElementText()
      number 
      
      slaveWebAddress $a[1] = label
      slaveWebAddress $a[2] = number
      }, error=function(e){})

    #Variable b
    tryCatch({
      label = remDr$findElement( using = "css", "#block-system-main > div > div > div > div > section > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div.field-label")
      label = label$getElementText()
      label = str_replace_all(label, "[[:punct:]]","")
      label = gsub(" ", "",label)
      label
      
      number = remDr$findElement( using = "css", "#block-system-main > div > div > div > div > section > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div.field-items")
      number = number$getElementText()
      number 
      
      slaveWebAddress$b[1] = label
      slaveWebAddress$b[2] = number
    }, error=function(e){})
    
    #Variable c
    tryCatch({
      label = remDr$findElement( using = "css", "#block-system-main > div > div > div > div > section > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(2) > div.field-label")
      label = label$getElementText()
      label = str_replace_all(label, "[[:punct:]]","")
      label = gsub(" ", "",label)
      label
      
      
      number = remDr$findElement( using = "css", "#block-system-main > div > div > div > div > section > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(2) > div.field-items")
      number = number$getElementText()
      number 
      
      slaveWebAddress$c[1] = label
      slaveWebAddress$c[2] = number
      }, 

      error=function(e){})
    
    #Convert first row into header
    names(slaveWebAddress) = as.matrix(slaveWebAddress[1, ])
    slaveWebAddress = slaveWebAddress[-1, ]
    slaveWebAddress[] = lapply(slaveWebAddress, function(x) 
    type.convert(as.character(x)))
    slaveWebAddress
    
#Delete with NA
slaveWebAddress = slaveWebAddress[, colSums(is.na(slaveWebAddress)) !=   nrow(slaveWebAddress)]
    
masterWebAddress = rbind.fill(slaveWebAddress,masterWebAddress)
  
  rm(slaveWebAddress) # or gc()
    
  }, error=function(e){})
  
 write.csv(masterWebAddress,"C:/Users/TESTING.csv", row.names = FALSE)
 }
masterWebAddress
```

Comment: Please include the code you used starting with `library(rvest)` or whatever libraries you're using, then the code (loop, scrape etc). That way we can run it and quickly find the problem